# How to do like search in VI

Tags: vi

i want to do a like search in vi. e.g. i use the command
vi test.log
the file opens. now i want to do a forward search and i am looking for 
[string1]%[string2] where % implies there can be any number of character in between these two strings (in a line). We have this kind of search in oracle(e.g. we often search for 'pattern%') . How to implement it in vi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there must be at least one character between the strings:

```
/string1.\+string2
```

If there needn't be any characters between the strings:

```
/string1.*string2
```

To use these, just start typing it; the leading `/` will enter Vim's search mode. Note that you may have to escape some of the characters in `string1` and `string2` if they have special meaning in Vim's regex syntax.

Explanation:

- `.` stands for any character (you can use `\w` if you just want to match "word" characters; i.e. letters, digits, and underscores).
- `*` means "0 or more instances of the preceding pattern".
- `\+` means "1 or more instances of the preceding pattern".

Vim's regex syntax is slightly different from the standard Perl regex syntax, which is why the `+` quantifier needs a slash in front of it. Read more here: http://www.softpanorama.org/Editors/Vimorama/vim_regular_expressions.shtml

Answer (score 1):

As soon as your file is open, just type:

```
/string1.*string2
```

`/` introduces a search

`.` means any character

`*` means any number of it (i.e., any number of any character)